# static tableview - cells initially off screen not updating

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I call the following method in viewWillAppear() in my tableview controller to load up my static cells with the data I want to display. Sections 1 & 2 display correctly. Section 3 doesn't load at all. However, when I change the tableview settings within storyboard from grouped to plain the first cell in section 2 displays correctly. It seems to me that the cells that are not initially visible when the view appears onscreen do not get loaded correctly.

```
-(void)loadCells
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];

//Section 0
cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
cell.textLabel.text = ...;
cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]];
cell.textLabel.text = ...;
cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0]];
cell.textLabel.text = ...;

// Section 1
cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]];
cell.textLabel.text = ...;
cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:1]];
cell.textLabel.text = ...;
cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:1]];
cell.textLabel.text = ...;
cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:1]];
cell.textLabel.text = ...;

// Section 2
cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:2]];
cell.textLabel.text = @"Testing"; 
cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:2]];
cell.textLabel.text = ...;
cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:2]];
cell.textLabel.text = ...;
cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:2]];
cell.textLabel.text = ...;
cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:2]];
cell.textLabel.text = ...;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the way to populate a table view with static cells. You should make IBOutlets to the labels from the table view controller, and then set the value of the labels in the normal way.

Comment: Thanks - much appreciated. Works and is clean.